# Where should you place pricing information so it is seen?

Tags: call-to-action, first-impression, pricing

I am currently running a screencast service for developers who want to learn about python.

I charge a small fee of 9 dollars a month. I have been good about emailing my potential customers or people who signed up and didn't subscribe. Some of them told me they didn't even know payment was an option.

This is huge concern, how can I make it obvious? I am clearly doing something wrong. I could just make it bigger but I would like to keep it tasteful.

I have added a current mock up of the site.

[image: Current Site]

Comment: Is this what your customers are currently seeing? I'm not seeing how you could "Sign Up" without "Subscribing". That button seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 4):

Don't put your price inside the interaction point. If I am looking for a price then buttons are perceived as grey matter. I don't expect to find the answer there. I'm looking for specific visual clues: a dollar sign ($), the words "price" or "for only", a number with .99 after it.

I can appreciate wanting to be tasteful, but your primary goal is communication. Try putting the price to the left of the button, in an accent color, and in a little larger type. Right now you've painted such an even story I have to actually read everything to understand what is going on. People scan, they don't read. Chunk out the information and start sentences with labeling words that get their subject across quickly.

Look at it like this. Which of these approaches is easier to digest?

--

[Sign up now $9 a month]

--

**$9 a month** [Sign up now]

--

The first line combines a few separate things into one item, which makes the communication harder to parse. It is telling you the price, that you can sign up immediately, and also that this a button that takes you to sign up. The user needs this information, but giving it all at once requires a heavier cognitive load. They not only have to process the information, they also have to make a choice. A CTA should only ask the user to make one decision, but this single button needs them to make two: "Am I ready to sign up?" and "Do I want to pay this much?" The questions are also in the wrong order. I am not ready to sign up until I know the price is right, but the first call to action I read is "sign up."

The second line breaks these two decisions apart. The user sees the price and thinks, "Am I willing to pay this amount?". With only one question, they can think less, which will keep them more engaged. Then their eyes can scan right and see the button, and then they'll decide "Do I want to sign up?" having already decided whether or not the price is acceptable.

In addition to burying the price, you've hidden Python in the subhead, in a lowercase no less. That should be in the headline, or at the very least the first word of the subhead. "From Novice to Neckbeard: **Python** training in weekly bite-sized podcasts." If the entire site is about Python, that should be immediately apparent when I hit the page. Users evaluate your site in 2 seconds. That single word needs to be processed within that time, as it is the core subject of the site.

Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change the top right "Sign up" button to "Sign up now for $9". Then both routes to signing up clearly indicates payment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people don't even read the site description and start looking for Sign Up button in the top right corner, so this might be the case. I just checked your website and I see that the sign up process is super simple (which is really good), but you can easily miss the text about $9 subscription.

Here's a regular use-case for you: 
I just entered my email and password, then I confirmed email, go login to your website... 
What's next? Where is the info about paying 9$? How do I even know about this option?

Upd. I mean I see that after you select some screencast you are redirected to payment page, but how do I know it if I'm logged in for the 1st time?